# Constructing a transition matrix from two vectors in R

Tags: r

I am trying to visualize the transition frequency of a process. I have the following data>

```
from  to
1    4  
4    5
1    3
1    3
4    5
...
```

What I am trying to do is create a heatmap of frequency matrix of those transitions, so for upper example,

```
  1 3 4 5
1 0 2 1 0
3 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 2
5 0 0 0 0
```

Before I reinvent the wheel, are there any predefined functions in R, which could give me such result?

Thanks!

Comment: re the dupe target (see thelatemail answer), you need : `levs <- sort(union(df$from, df$to)) ; table(factor(df$from, levs), factor(df$to, levs))`

Comment: Also look at `igraph::from_adjacency`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df

  from to
1    1  4
2    4  5
3    1  3
4    1  3
5    4  5

df$count <- 1
df <- aggregate(count~from+to, data=df, sum)
nodes <- unique(c(df$from,df$to))
df1 <- merge(expand.grid(from=nodes, to=nodes), df, by=c('from','to'), all=TRUE)
df1$count[is.na(df1$count)] <- 0
library(reshape2)
dcast(df1, from~to, value.var = 'count')

  from 1 3 4 5
1    1 0 2 1 0
2    3 0 0 0 0
3    4 0 0 0 2
4    5 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks, this works!